# Custom trusted root certificates in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-phone-8

We are building a Windows Phone 8 App that needs to open an SSL TCP connection to a server. The server uses certificate issued from a custom Root certificate.

For Store Apps we can get around this by adding the root certificates to the Package.appxmanifest file as trusted CA's and after that the server certificate gets validated.

What is the Windows Phone 8 approach for this? How can I specify custom CA's as trusted roots for WP8?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports the [Windows.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.aspx) namespace.
Using it you can manually install the certificate as described in [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/05/including-self-signed-certificates-with-your-windows-runtime-based-windows-phone-8-1-apps.aspx).